# Increasing FTP Server download speed through multiple FTP Servers

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vps, sftp

I have developed a Freemium Software which can be downloaded.
I host the download on an Ubuntu FTP Server; in which I rented a Virtual Private Server to do this.

My concern is the download speeds. If 100 people are downloading at once, connection will be slowed down.

Is there a way for me to setup multiple FTP servers  to host same file by setting up additional VPS? I can't seem to find anywhere in google how to set this up.

OR

Is there a smarter way to achieve faster download speed?

Comment: What is your main concern - Disk IO? Network Bandwidth? How big is your file(s)?

Comment: In general people avoid FTP downloads and use the services of a CDN to ensure that their own server(s) and bandwidth won't be the bottleneck for either the initial download and/or future automated updates.